# Get SOLR index size

Tags: solr, sunspot

I am using Sunspot (Ruby/Rails) on top of SOLR in my webapp. Now I run into problems when SOLR hits Java heap space. I cannot figure out how to find the SOLR index size? Is there a way to find this out from command-line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for the physical on-disk size of the index, you can look at 'data/index' folder under 'dataDir' per the definition in solrconfig.xml.  For eg. in example index, it is example/solr/data/index folder.

If you are looking for count of the documents, then you can either look at stats.jsp page or search for "*:*".

If you are looking for understanding memory usage, you can start with the stats.jsp - and look at document count, various field cache size etc.

I am afraid you will need to do more research to understand your memory requirements, profile the application and plan for capacity.

Comment: That's correct. To have it through command line from the Solr directory:
`du -S * | grep index`

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is because of memory usage, not physical size. If you are running tomcat under Windows, you can fix this with the tomcat monitor tool pictured below. I recommend you give Solr 2048+ for the max value depending on the hardware. This will solve the error you are getting.  If you are running linux you will need to edit the java options to include *-xmx2048* and restart Tomcat.

[image: Tomcat Memory Setting]

---

If you really want to see the size of your index, another way would be to add the replication handler to your "solrconfig.xml". This handler allows you to make back ups of your Solr data, but also has a nifty gui that will show you index size and more.

```
<requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler">
   <str name="maxNumberOfBackups">1</str>
</requestHandler>
```

Then you can visit *http://[SolrServer]/solr/admin/replication/index.jsp* to see the index size in you're browser.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to see your memory consumption, I recommend you to use [MAT Tool](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/08/eclipse-memory-analyzer-mat.html) enjoy !:)